# Getting the first day of the month of a specific month/year

Tags: php, date

Is there a better way of returning the date for the first day of a specific month/year, than the following?

```
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');
$from = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? What you have seems fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That looks like the right way to do it to me. You might want to make it a function though.

Answer (score 12):

This is not exactly computationally elegant, but I like it because it's so readable:

```
strtotime("first day of this month");
```

Comment: Worth noting that variations like "first day of next month" and "first day of this month +2 month" also work.

Comment: Also worth noting that unlike sample in the question which has midnight as the time, this version uses the current hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: I like to use `$date = new DateTime('first day of this month'); $date->setTime(0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 8):

Why so complicated?

```
date("Y-m-01")
```

This will work just fine ;)

(Don't worry, I kicked myself hard for wasting an hour messing with `strtotime` before realising I could do this!)

Answer (score 2):

`date("Y-m-01")` will work perfectly;
I have used same technique to find record from first day of the month to current day.
Have a look at following lines of code:

```
if(!isset($FromDate))
          $FromDate=date('Y-m-01'); //date with current month's first day

if(!isset($ToDate))
         $ToDate=date('Y-m-d'); /////current date
```

I hope it will work according to requirements.